# Update/Add as separate service and Get as separate service

Tags: microservices

We started to migrate our existing project into microservice architecture. After going through a lot of videos/lectures, we came to a conclusion that a service should do one task and only one task and should be great at it. The services should be designed around `Noun` and `Verb`.

We have an entity which has basically CRUD operations. Now the add, update and delete are least used operations but GET requests at too high compared to those operations. Typically, update/add/delete are done by admin guys.

What we thought of is breaking the CRUD entity into  two services

- EntityCUDService (create/update/delete)
- EntityLookupService (get)

Now both these services point to the same collection in mongo or say some SQL.
Now if `EntityCUDService` has done some changes to collection/table then `EntityLookupService` fails.

We heard of maintaining semantic versioning, that sounds okay but We also heard microservices should not share model/data source. So what would be the optimal solution to handle this where we have tons of gets but tens of updates/adds of same entity

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are trying to open all the pandora boxes in one go. My suggestion would be to proceed with simplest solution of exposing CRUD operation for REST entity in one service. try to distribute your load using load balancer. Go  for CQRS if every thing else fails to satisfy required scale/load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a micro service should manage single entity. So in your case you can have one micro-service to manage the entity (for various operations on the entity). Now if you want to split the service again on the basis of read and write operation then you are following the CQRS pattern. In CQRS , you split your micro-service on the basis of read and write operations. So now you will have 2 services one called command service and other called query service over the same entity. I will suggest to go with one service first to manage the entity and then if required split it more for separate service for read and write operations. Again if you are going to use CQRS, then have a look at event sourcing as it nicely fits with CQRS in micro-services design.